# Menu hover, page's transparency become 0.5

Tags: jquery, html, css

Had totally no clue how to make a navigation menu, that when it hover, the whole page's transparency drop to 50% only. Can anyone advise me what is the css i write for this case?

jsfiddle.net/websensation/uMMPa

Comment: Show us your code? what do you have so far?

Comment: js fiddle pls ? although I think you should use css opacity property

Comment: had tried here.. but still doesnt works.. http://jsfiddle.net/websensation/uMMPa

Answer (score 0):

You tagged jQuery, so I was thinkin this may be helpful.

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#elementId').mouseenter(function() {
        $('body').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
    });
    $('#elementId').mouseout(function() {
        $('body').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
```

Where elementId is the id on the navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

you need a third element `<div class="modal-bg"></div>` between the navigation menu and the rest of the document to act like a filter similar to how the background of a modal work, you then add transparency to this layer, like:

```
.modal-bg {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

It doesn't make sense to just fade out everything other than the navigation menu.

+1 @somdow, @user3161892, what's your code example?

Comment: thanks for the idea. I tried with it, still doesn't works. mind any extra help here? http://jsfiddle.net/websensation/uMMPa/